# Why does GPSBabel turn a short GPX route into a big KML with waypoints?

Tags: kml, gpsbabel

I read the online help file before asking but didn't find what's wrong with the following command to convert a small GPX file from [www.cycle.travel](http://www.cycle.travel) to a KML that I can use with a smartphone application:

```
c:\GPSBabel>gpsbabel.exe -N  -i gpx -f input.gpx -o kml -F output.kml
```

Here's the input file (1,216 bytes):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<gpx version="1.0" creator="cycle.travel"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/0"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/0 http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/0/gpx.xsd">
<trk>
<name>ACTIVE LOG</name>
<trkseg>
<trkpt lat="48.85324" lon="2.35027" />
<trkpt lat="48.85315" lon="2.35056" />
<trkpt lat="48.85363" lon="2.35090" />
<trkpt lat="48.85438" lon="2.34975" />
<trkpt lat="48.85507" lon="2.35025" />
<trkpt lat="48.85582" lon="2.35082" />
<trkpt lat="48.85609" lon="2.35063" />
<trkpt lat="48.85680" lon="2.35107" />
<trkpt lat="48.85747" lon="2.35148" />
<trkpt lat="48.85751" lon="2.35151" />
<trkpt lat="48.85807" lon="2.34969" />
<trkpt lat="48.85854" lon="2.34823" />
<trkpt lat="48.86039" lon="2.34233" />
<trkpt lat="48.86052" lon="2.34195" />
<trkpt lat="48.86321" lon="2.33377" />
<trkpt lat="48.86372" lon="2.33220" />
<trkpt lat="48.86378" lon="2.33199" />
<trkpt lat="48.86636" lon="2.32426" />
<trkpt lat="48.86639" lon="2.32356" />
<trkpt lat="48.86639" lon="2.32344" />
<trkpt lat="48.86639" lon="2.32340" />
<trkpt lat="48.86661" lon="2.32197" />
<trkpt lat="48.86588" lon="2.32090" />
</trkseg></trk></gpx>
```

And here's the output file (17,254 bytes):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2">
  <Document>
    <name>GPS device</name>
    <snippet>Created mer. juil. 15 18:12:19 2015</snippet>
    <LookAt>
      <longitude>2.336205</longitude>
      <latitude>48.859880</latitude>
      <range>3505.359392</range>
    </LookAt>
    <!-- Normal track style -->
    <Style id="track_n">
      <IconStyle>
        <scale>.5</scale>
        <Icon>
          <href>http://earth.google.com/images/kml-icons/track-directional/track-none.png</href>
        </Icon>
      </IconStyle>
      <LabelStyle>
        <scale>0</scale>
      </LabelStyle>
    </Style>
    <!-- Highlighted track style -->
    <Style id="track_h">
      <IconStyle>
        <scale>1.2</scale>
        <Icon>
          <href>http://earth.google.com/images/kml-icons/track-directional/track-none.png</href>
        </Icon>
      </IconStyle>
    </Style>
    <StyleMap id="track">
      <Pair>
        <key>normal</key>
        <styleUrl>#track_n</styleUrl>
      </Pair>
      <Pair>
        <key>highlight</key>
        <styleUrl>#track_h</styleUrl>
      </Pair>
    </StyleMap>
    <!-- Normal waypoint style -->
    <Style id="waypoint_n">
      <IconStyle>
        <Icon>
          <href>http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/pal4/icon61.png</href>
        </Icon>
      </IconStyle>
    </Style>
    <!-- Highlighted waypoint style -->
    <Style id="waypoint_h">
      <IconStyle>
        <scale>1.2</scale>
        <Icon>
          <href>http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/pal4/icon61.png</href>
        </Icon>
      </IconStyle>
    </Style>
    <StyleMap id="waypoint">
      <Pair>
        <key>normal</key>
        <styleUrl>#waypoint_n</styleUrl>
      </Pair>
      <Pair>
        <key>highlight</key>
        <styleUrl>#waypoint_h</styleUrl>
      </Pair>
    </StyleMap>
    <Style id="lineStyle">
      <LineStyle>
        <color>99ffac59</color>
        <width>6</width>
      </LineStyle>
    </Style>
    <Folder>
      <name>Tracks</name>
      <Folder>
        <name>ACTIVE LOG</name>
        <snippet/>
        <description>
<![CDATA[<table>
<tr><td><b>Distance</b> 1.9 mi </td></tr>
</table>]]>
</description>
        <Folder>
          <name>Points</name>
          <Placemark>
            <name>ACTIVE LOG-0</name>
            <snippet/>
            <description><![CDATA[
<table>
<tr><td>Longitude: 2.350270 </td></tr>
<tr><td>Latitude: 48.853240 </td></tr>
<tr><td>Heading: 2.1 </td></tr>
</table>
]]></description>
            <LookAt>
              <longitude>2.350270</longitude>
              <latitude>48.853240</latitude>
              <tilt>66</tilt>
            </LookAt>
            <styleUrl>#track</styleUrl>
            <Point>
              <coordinates>2.350270,48.853240</coordinates>
            </Point>
          </Placemark>
          <Placemark>
            <name>ACTIVE LOG-1</name>
            <snippet/>
            <description><![CDATA[
<table>
<tr><td>Longitude: 2.350560 </td></tr>
<tr><td>Latitude: 48.853150 </td></tr>
<tr><td>Heading: 115.3 </td></tr>
</table>
]]></description>
            <LookAt>
              <longitude>2.350560</longitude>
              <latitude>48.853150</latitude>
              <tilt>66</tilt>
            </LookAt>
            <styleUrl>#track</styleUrl>
            <Point>
              <coordinates>2.350560,48.853150</coordinates>
            </Point>
          </Placemark>
          <Placemark>
            <name>ACTIVE LOG-2</name>
            <snippet/>
            <description><![CDATA[
<table>
<tr><td>Longitude: 2.350900 </td></tr>
<tr><td>Latitude: 48.853630 </td></tr>
<tr><td>Heading: 25.0 </td></tr>
</table>
]]></description>
            <LookAt>
              <longitude>2.350900</longitude>
              <latitude>48.853630</latitude>
              <tilt>66</tilt>
            </LookAt>
            <styleUrl>#track</styleUrl>
            <Point>
              <coordinates>2.350900,48.853630</coordinates>
            </Point>
          </Placemark>
          <Placemark>
            <name>ACTIVE LOG-3</name>
            <snippet/>
            <description><![CDATA[
<table>
<tr><td>Longitude: 2.349750 </td></tr>
<tr><td>Latitude: 48.854380 </td></tr>
<tr><td>Heading: 314.7 </td></tr>
</table>
]]></description>
            <LookAt>
              <longitude>2.349750</longitude>
              <latitude>48.854380</latitude>
              <tilt>66</tilt>
            </LookAt>
            <styleUrl>#track</styleUrl>
            <Point>
              <coordinates>2.349750,48.854380</coordinates>
            </Point>
          </Placemark>
          <Placemark>
            <name>ACTIVE LOG-4</name>
            <snippet/>
            <description><![CDATA[
<table>
<tr><td>Longitude: 2.350250 </td></tr>
<tr><td>Latitude: 48.855070 </td></tr>
<tr><td>Heading: 25.5 </td></tr>
</table>
]]></description>
            <LookAt>
              <longitude>2.350250</longitude>
              <latitude>48.855070</latitude>
              <tilt>66</tilt>
            </LookAt>
            <styleUrl>#track</styleUrl>
            <Point>
              <coordinates>2.350250,48.855070</coordinates>
            </Point>
          </Placemark>
          <Placemark>
            <name>ACTIVE LOG-5</name>
            <snippet/>
            <description><![CDATA[
<table>
<tr><td>Longitude: 2.350820 </td></tr>
<tr><td>Latitude: 48.855820 </td></tr>
<tr><td>Heading: 26.6 </td></tr>
</table>
]]></description>
            <LookAt>
              <longitude>2.350820</longitude>
              <latitude>48.855820</latitude>
              <tilt>66</tilt>
            </LookAt>
            <styleUrl>#track</styleUrl>
            <Point>
              <coordinates>2.350820,48.855820</coordinates>
            </Point>
          </Placemark>
          <Placemark>
            <name>ACTIVE LOG-6</name>
            <snippet/>
            <description><![CDATA[
<table>
<tr><td>Longitude: 2.350630 </td></tr>
<tr><td>Latitude: 48.856090 </td></tr>
<tr><td>Heading: 335.2 </td></tr>
</table>
]]></description>
            <LookAt>
              <longitude>2.350630</longitude>
              <latitude>48.856090</latitude>
              <tilt>66</tilt>
            </LookAt>
            <styleUrl>#track</styleUrl>
            <Point>
              <coordinates>2.350630,48.856090</coordinates>
            </Point>
          </Placemark>
          <Placemark>
            <name>ACTIVE LOG-7</name>
            <snippet/>
            <description><![CDATA[
<table>
<tr><td>Longitude: 2.351070 </td></tr>
<tr><td>Latitude: 48.856800 </td></tr>
<tr><td>Heading: 22.2 </td></tr>
</table>
]]></description>
            <LookAt>
              <longitude>2.351070</longitude>
              <latitude>48.856800</latitude>
              <tilt>66</tilt>
            </LookAt>
            <styleUrl>#track</styleUrl>
            <Point>
              <coordinates>2.351070,48.856800</coordinates>
            </Point>
          </Placemark>
          <Placemark>
            <name>ACTIVE LOG-8</name>
            <snippet/>
            <description><![CDATA[
<table>
<tr><td>Longitude: 2.351480 </td></tr>
<tr><td>Latitude: 48.857470 </td></tr>
<tr><td>Heading: 21.9 </td></tr>
</table>
]]></description>
            <LookAt>
              <longitude>2.351480</longitude>
              <latitude>48.857470</latitude>
              <tilt>66</tilt>
            </LookAt>
            <styleUrl>#track</styleUrl>
            <Point>
              <coordinates>2.351480,48.857470</coordinates>
            </Point>
          </Placemark>
          <Placemark>
            <name>ACTIVE LOG-9</name>
            <snippet/>
            <description><![CDATA[
<table>
<tr><td>Longitude: 2.351510 </td></tr>
<tr><td>Latitude: 48.857510 </td></tr>
<tr><td>Heading: 26.3 </td></tr>
</table>
]]></description>
            <LookAt>
              <longitude>2.351510</longitude>
              <latitude>48.857510</latitude>
              <tilt>66</tilt>
            </LookAt>
            <styleUrl>#track</styleUrl>
            <Point>
              <coordinates>2.351510,48.857510</coordinates>
            </Point>
          </Placemark>
          <Placemark>
            <name>ACTIVE LOG-10</name>
            <snippet/>
            <description><![CDATA[
<table>
<tr><td>Longitude: 2.349690 </td></tr>
<tr><td>Latitude: 48.858070 </td></tr>
<tr><td>Heading: 295.1 </td></tr>
</table>
]]></description>
            <LookAt>
              <longitude>2.349690</longitude>
              <latitude>48.858070</latitude>
              <tilt>66</tilt>
            </LookAt>
            <styleUrl>#track</styleUrl>
            <Point>
              <coordinates>2.349690,48.858070</coordinates>
            </Point>
          </Placemark>
          <Placemark>
            <name>ACTIVE LOG-11</name>
            <snippet/>
            <description><![CDATA[
<table>
<tr><td>Longitude: 2.348230 </td></tr>
<tr><td>Latitude: 48.858540 </td></tr>
<tr><td>Heading: 296.1 </td></tr>
</table>
]]></description>
            <LookAt>
              <longitude>2.348230</longitude>
              <latitude>48.858540</latitude>
              <tilt>66</tilt>
            </LookAt>
            <styleUrl>#track</styleUrl>
            <Point>
              <coordinates>2.348230,48.858540</coordinates>
            </Point>
          </Placemark>
          <Placemark>
            <name>ACTIVE LOG-12</name>
            <snippet/>
            <description><![CDATA[
<table>
<tr><td>Longitude: 2.342330 </td></tr>
<tr><td>Latitude: 48.860390 </td></tr>
<tr><td>Heading: 295.5 </td></tr>
</table>
]]></description>
            <LookAt>
              <longitude>2.342330</longitude>
              <latitude>48.860390</latitude>
              <tilt>66</tilt>
            </LookAt>
            <styleUrl>#track</styleUrl>
            <Point>
              <coordinates>2.342330,48.860390</coordinates>
            </Point>
          </Placemark>
          <Placemark>
            <name>ACTIVE LOG-13</name>
            <snippet/>
            <description><![CDATA[
<table>
<tr><td>Longitude: 2.341950 </td></tr>
<tr><td>Latitude: 48.860520 </td></tr>
<tr><td>Heading: 297.5 </td></tr>
</table>
]]></description>
            <LookAt>
              <longitude>2.341950</longitude>
              <latitude>48.860520</latitude>
              <tilt>66</tilt>
            </LookAt>
            <styleUrl>#track</styleUrl>
            <Point>
              <coordinates>2.341950,48.860520</coordinates>
            </Point>
          </Placemark>
          <Placemark>
            <name>ACTIVE LOG-14</name>
            <snippet/>
            <description><![CDATA[
<table>
<tr><td>Longitude: 2.333770 </td></tr>
<tr><td>Latitude: 48.863210 </td></tr>
<tr><td>Heading: 296.6 </td></tr>
</table>
]]></description>
            <LookAt>
              <longitude>2.333770</longitude>
              <latitude>48.863210</latitude>
              <tilt>66</tilt>
            </LookAt>
            <styleUrl>#track</styleUrl>
            <Point>
              <coordinates>2.333770,48.863210</coordinates>
            </Point>
          </Placemark>
          <Placemark>
            <name>ACTIVE LOG-15</name>
            <snippet/>
            <description><![CDATA[
<table>
<tr><td>Longitude: 2.332200 </td></tr>
<tr><td>Latitude: 48.863720 </td></tr>
<tr><td>Heading: 296.3 </td></tr>
</table>
]]></description>
            <LookAt>
              <longitude>2.332200</longitude>
              <latitude>48.863720</latitude>
              <tilt>66</tilt>
            </LookAt>
            <styleUrl>#track</styleUrl>
            <Point>
              <coordinates>2.332200,48.863720</coordinates>
            </Point>
          </Placemark>
          <Placemark>
            <name>ACTIVE LOG-16</name>
            <snippet/>
            <description><![CDATA[
<table>
<tr><td>Longitude: 2.331990 </td></tr>
<tr><td>Latitude: 48.863780 </td></tr>
<tr><td>Heading: 293.5 </td></tr>
</table>
]]></description>
            <LookAt>
              <longitude>2.331990</longitude>
              <latitude>48.863780</latitude>
              <tilt>66</tilt>
            </LookAt>
            <styleUrl>#track</styleUrl>
            <Point>
              <coordinates>2.331990,48.863780</coordinates>
            </Point>
          </Placemark>
          <Placemark>
            <name>ACTIVE LOG-17</name>
            <snippet/>
            <description><![CDATA[
<table>
<tr><td>Longitude: 2.324260 </td></tr>
<tr><td>Latitude: 48.866360 </td></tr>
<tr><td>Heading: 296.9 </td></tr>
</table>
]]></description>
            <LookAt>
              <longitude>2.324260</longitude>
              <latitude>48.866360</latitude>
              <tilt>66</tilt>
            </LookAt>
            <styleUrl>#track</styleUrl>
            <Point>
              <coordinates>2.324260,48.866360</coordinates>
            </Point>
          </Placemark>
          <Placemark>
            <name>ACTIVE LOG-18</name>
            <snippet/>
            <description><![CDATA[
<table>
<tr><td>Longitude: 2.323560 </td></tr>
<tr><td>Latitude: 48.866390 </td></tr>
<tr><td>Heading: 273.7 </td></tr>
</table>
]]></description>
            <LookAt>
              <longitude>2.323560</longitude>
              <latitude>48.866390</latitude>
              <tilt>66</tilt>
            </LookAt>
            <styleUrl>#track</styleUrl>
            <Point>
              <coordinates>2.323560,48.866390</coordinates>
            </Point>
          </Placemark>
          <Placemark>
            <name>ACTIVE LOG-19</name>
            <snippet/>
            <description><![CDATA[
<table>
<tr><td>Longitude: 2.323440 </td></tr>
<tr><td>Latitude: 48.866390 </td></tr>
<tr><td>Heading: 270.0 </td></tr>
</table>
]]></description>
            <LookAt>
              <longitude>2.323440</longitude>
              <latitude>48.866390</latitude>
              <tilt>66</tilt>
            </LookAt>
            <styleUrl>#track</styleUrl>
            <Point>
              <coordinates>2.323440,48.866390</coordinates>
            </Point>
          </Placemark>
          <Placemark>
            <name>ACTIVE LOG-20</name>
            <snippet/>
            <description><![CDATA[
<table>
<tr><td>Longitude: 2.323400 </td></tr>
<tr><td>Latitude: 48.866390 </td></tr>
<tr><td>Heading: 270.0 </td></tr>
</table>
]]></description>
            <LookAt>
              <longitude>2.323400</longitude>
              <latitude>48.866390</latitude>
              <tilt>66</tilt>
            </LookAt>
            <styleUrl>#track</styleUrl>
            <Point>
              <coordinates>2.323400,48.866390</coordinates>
            </Point>
          </Placemark>
          <Placemark>
            <name>ACTIVE LOG-21</name>
            <snippet/>
            <description><![CDATA[
<table>
<tr><td>Longitude: 2.321970 </td></tr>
<tr><td>Latitude: 48.866610 </td></tr>
<tr><td>Heading: 283.2 </td></tr>
</table>
]]></description>
            <LookAt>
              <longitude>2.321970</longitude>
              <latitude>48.866610</latitude>
              <tilt>66</tilt>
            </LookAt>
            <styleUrl>#track</styleUrl>
            <Point>
              <coordinates>2.321970,48.866610</coordinates>
            </Point>
          </Placemark>
          <Placemark>
            <name>ACTIVE LOG-22</name>
            <snippet/>
            <description><![CDATA[
<table>
<tr><td>Longitude: 2.320900 </td></tr>
<tr><td>Latitude: 48.865880 </td></tr>
<tr><td>Heading: 224.0 </td></tr>
</table>
]]></description>
            <LookAt>
              <longitude>2.320900</longitude>
              <latitude>48.865880</latitude>
              <tilt>66</tilt>
            </LookAt>
            <styleUrl>#track</styleUrl>
            <Point>
              <coordinates>2.320900,48.865880</coordinates>
            </Point>
          </Placemark>
        </Folder>
        <Placemark>
          <name>Path</name>
          <styleUrl>#lineStyle</styleUrl>
          <LineString>
            <tessellate>1</tessellate>
            <coordinates>
2.350270,48.853240
2.350560,48.853150
2.350900,48.853630
2.349750,48.854380
2.350250,48.855070
2.350820,48.855820
2.350630,48.856090
2.351070,48.856800
2.351480,48.857470
2.351510,48.857510
2.349690,48.858070
2.348230,48.858540
2.342330,48.860390
2.341950,48.860520
2.333770,48.863210
2.332200,48.863720
2.331990,48.863780
2.324260,48.866360
2.323560,48.866390
2.323440,48.866390
2.323400,48.866390
2.321970,48.866610
2.320900,48.865880
</coordinates>
          </LineString>
        </Placemark>
      </Folder>
    </Folder>
  </Document>
</kml>
```

The output is much bigger and, when imported into the smartphone, the route is displayed as a line + waypoints instead of a simple line.

What should I do?

---

For others' benefit, the answer is to add this switch:

```
gpsbabel -i gpx -f input.gpx -o kml,points=0 -F output.kml
```

Comment: Is the edit you made the actual answer? It's a good idea to answer your own question (and even accept it) as you would any other question - with a writeup about why it works and what the results are.